# Filter inside groups Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I've got grouped dataframe and I want to filter values inside each group depending on those values.

I tried:

```
figure_cols = list("ABC")

def get_threshold_for_IV(gr_vals):
    return (gr_vals[figure_cols].max())/(gr_vals["A"].count())

def filter_IV(group):
    A_tr, B_tr, C_tr = get_threshold_for_IV(group)
    return group[(group.A >= A_tr) & (group.B >= B_tr) & (group.C >= C_tr)]

# 1 attempt
grouped.apply(filter_IV)

# 2 attempt
for name, group in grouped:
    A_tr, B_tr, C_tr = get_threshold_for_IV(group)
    group = group[(group.A < A_tr) & (group.B < B_tr) & (group.C < C_tr)]
```

But nothing works. Data is not changed.
My functions works fine. If I insert `print` in cycle I can see filtered result.

Other thing I should say, that I want to have grouped object after filter operation to do further manipulations

I've read docs, but it looks like i'm blind for it. Can anybody help?

**EDIT**

Added self contained example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'gr' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                         'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'A' : np.arange(8),
                   'B' : np.random.randn(8),
                   'C' : np.random.randn(8)})

def filter_gt_3(group):
    return group[group.A < 3]

grouped = df.groupby('gr')
for name, group in grouped:
    print 'group name: %s' % name
    print group
    group = filter_gt_3(group)
    print "\nfiltered"
    print group


print '\n----------\n'
print 'Nothing filtered:\n'
for name, group in grouped:
    print 'group name: %s' % name
    print group
```

> Output

```
group name: bar
   A         B         C   gr
1  1  1.486028 -0.382597  bar
3  3 -0.501757 -0.771807  bar
5  5 -0.836930 -1.514824  bar

filtered
   A         B         C   gr
1  1  1.486028 -0.382597  bar

group name: foo
   A         B         C   gr
0  0  0.678104 -0.940245  foo
2  2  1.539903  1.460493  foo
4  4 -0.033421 -1.078566  foo
6  6  1.146298  0.039721  foo
7  7  1.095707 -1.032275  foo

filtered
   A         B         C   gr
0  0  0.678104 -0.940245  foo
2  2  1.539903  1.460493  foo

----------

Nothing filtered:

group name: bar
   A         B         C   gr
1  1  1.486028 -0.382597  bar
3  3 -0.501757 -0.771807  bar
5  5 -0.836930 -1.514824  bar
group name: foo
   A         B         C   gr
0  0  0.678104 -0.940245  foo
2  2  1.539903  1.460493  foo
4  4 -0.033421 -1.078566  foo
6  6  1.146298  0.039721  foo
7  7  1.095707 -1.032275  foo
```

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained, runnable example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @BrenBarn I've added example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `group = filter_gt_3(group)` doesn't modify the original data.  It just assigns the filtered data to a local variable called `group`.  Likewise, just calling `groupby.apply` (as in your first example) doesn't modify anything.  If you want to do anything with the filtered data, you need to use the value *returned* by these operations.

If you want to get the filtered data, do something like

```
new_data = df.groupby('gr').apply(filter_gt_3)
```

Note that this will also not modify the original data: it creates a *new* DataFrame and assigns it to `new_data`.  You can assign it back to the original name if you like (e.g., `df = df.groupby...`)

Comment: yes, I understand that. So to perform other manipulations with same groups I should `groupby` again?

Comment: @re-gor: Yes.  (Or you can write a function that does all the manipulations you want in one go.)